# Count level of object depth

Tags: javascript, object

I have a **javascript** object and I would like to count the number of nested depth.

Example Object

**Answer** should be equal 4 (count level depth)

```
data: {
first: [
  {
    value: '',
    children: [
      {
       value: '',
       children: [
          {
            value: '',
            children: [
              {
                value: '',
                children: [],
              },
              {
                 value: '',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
],
```

Comment: ... and how have you tried to achieve this so far?

Comment: Use [recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recursion/info).

Comment: @C.Braun: It overlaps a bit, but I don't think it's a duplicate.  That asks about a generic object.  This asks about a specific structure (`children`, etc.)

Comment: Weclome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).  Please note that this is not a code-writing service.  We want to help, but expect you to put in a reasonable amount of effort too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that it is a tree (no nested objects link to ancestors) you can simply navigate the structure

```
function treeHeight(node) {
    return node.children.reduce(function (maxHeight, node) {
        return Math.max(maxHeight, treeHeight(node) + 1);
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Presumably `maxDepth` should be `maxHeight`.

Comment: Thanks @ScottSauyet that was a typo ;-)